# CSS bootstrap text-right not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form and I split up my form into 2 columns using col-md-6 so half the fields go on the left and the other half go on the right. Now what I am trying to do is have all my fields on the left alight to the right so there is no extra space and the form looks more centered.

Here is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="first_name">Firstname:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name"
    placeholder="First Name" name="first_name">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="last_name">Lastname:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"
    placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
    placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address1">Address
   Line 1:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1"
    placeholder="Address Line 1" name="address1">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address2">Address
   Line 2:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2"
    placeholder="Address Line 2" name="address2">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="city">City:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City"
    name="city">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="country">Country:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="state">State:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
    <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
    <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
    <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
    <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zip">Postal Code:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip"
    placeholder="Postal Code" name="zip">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="night_phone_a">Phone:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <div class="form-group phone-number">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
     <input type="tel" name="night_phone_a" class="form-control"
      value="" size="3" maxlength="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
     <input type="tel" name="night_phone_b" class="form-control"
      value="" size="3" maxlength="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <input type="tel" name="night_phone_c" class="form-control"
      value="" size="4" maxlength="4">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using pull-right on the first col-md-6 and I have also tried text-right and neither of them work. How do I get the fields in the first col-md-6 align to the right?

Comment: You likely need to float the content in the boostrap `div`s to the right then. I'm guessing `text-right` isn't working because the `input`s or `.form-group`s have additional styling (either block-level or alignment) that's effectively rendering `text-right` useless.  Maybe something like `#formID > div:first-of-type .form-group { float: right; }` to only apply this to the first/left column

Comment: Your request seems unclear; each `form-group` is already taking up 100% of the column width excluding the padding native to Bootstrap's Grid system. Do you just want to remove that padding so that the spacing between each column is less?

Comment: But `.text-right` on the first `.col-md-6` *does* align the text to the right for the labels.  I don't understand what the issue is. https://jsfiddle.net/f9jcebr2/show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-right control-label col-sm-2" for="first_name">Firstname:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name"
    placeholder="First Name" name="first_name">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-right control-label col-sm-2" for="last_name">Lastname:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"
    placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class=" text-right control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
    placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-right control-label col-sm-2" for="address1">Address
   Line 1:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1"
    placeholder="Address Line 1" name="address1">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-right control-label col-sm-2" for="address2">Address
   Line 2:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2"
    placeholder="Address Line 2" name="address2">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="city">City:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City"
    name="city">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="country">Country:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="state">State:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
    <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
    <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
    <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
    <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zip">Postal Code:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip"
    placeholder="Postal Code" name="zip">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="night_phone_a">Phone:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   <div class="form-group phone-number">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
     <input type="tel" name="night_phone_a" class="form-control"
      value="" size="3" maxlength="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
     <input type="tel" name="night_phone_b" class="form-control"
      value="" size="3" maxlength="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
     <input type="tel" name="night_phone_c" class="form-control"
      value="" size="4" maxlength="4">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then ensure you use an outer .form-horizontal class to house all your divs thats has .form-group. You can refer to bootstrap documentation again , see here how it is used   https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Comment: or better yet, straight from the source :) http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I looked at the bootstrap CSS and I see they address "text-center" but they don't address "text-right", but they do address "**text-end**" and that did it for me.

Comment: /node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css